# Citations overflowing

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm having an odd problem with the citations. Whenever I call the, after rendering, I get odd formats like:

> [Subramanian et al(2006)Subramanian, Ramamoorthy, Stone, and Kuipers]

It's supposed to say only Subramian et al and the year. And the text is overflowing the paragraph structure (it isn't aligned with the paragraph).

Any idea where could I look into to fix this.

The style used is spbasic.bst.

And I'm giving the input as a ".bib" file

Comment: Hello and welcome to tex.sx! A minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would surely help people reproduce your issue and help you fix it.

Comment: It's clear that you are using a `natbib` compatible bibstyle. So you should use `\usepackage{natbib}` first.

Comment: @Leo: Please convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep: done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contents of generated `.bbl` file show that you're using a `natbib` compatible bibstyle. Therefore, you should use

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

to get proper result. Further options may be needed, see the document of `natbib`.